# ¿ como puedo operar el valor guardado de la posición de un valor de un arreglo?

Tags: c++, c

Como **puedo operar el valor de la posición de un arreglo** por ejemplo `s[3];` quisiera sumar el valor de la matriz por ejemplo la posición dos mas 3.

```
#include <iostream>
            
 using namespace std;
        
 int main(){
     
    
    
      int s[]={1,2,3,4,5}
      
      valor = s[3] + 4;
    
    
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: No entiendo cual es tu pregunta. Si tu pregunta es como acceder a un miembro del arreglo, puede usar el operador `[]`, si no es esa, puedes clarificarla?

Comment: Como recomendación se más limpio con tu código y de favor modifica tu pregunta, pues tiene errores graves de redacción. Realmente no se entiende.

Comment: @Pablochaches, hola, tengo una duda, hace tiempo escribí esta pregunta y cuando la escribí no tenia ningún sentido y estaba frustrado, así que la corregí pero creo que no tiene caso porque es muy boba, entonces ¿no se si la debo corregirla mas? o ¿si puedo cambiar completamente el sentido de la pregunta?.

Comment: @josealejandrovaroncarreño Lo que te recomendaría es que la volvieras a publicar. Una pregunta de hace año y medio con un score de `-5` no va a recibir actividad.

Comment: A ver si entiendo lo que quieres hacer. Por "quisiera sumar el valor de la matriz por ejemplo la posición dos mas 3", supongo que buscas hacer alto tipo `s[2] = s[2] + 3`?

Comment: @Pablochaches, hay esta el problema, ya no puedo publicar preguntas entonces, quiero corregir lo que publique mal para volver a activar la cuenta, pero no se como, si elimino las preguntas o que puedo hacer ?

Comment: Fijate que si te bloquearon la cuenta, ahi si no te puedo ayudar. Te sale algun tipo de error al publicar preguntas nuevas?

Comment: @Pablochaches me dice que no cree otra cuenta y que intente corregir los errores como las preguntas mal planteadas, pero lo hago y sigue igual, no se como pueda hacer para subir la reputación rápido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para empezar, las posiciones en los arreglos empiezan a enumerarse desde el 0. Si tu arreglo tiene n=5 elementos, las posiciones van desde el 0 hasta el n-1.

```
int s[]={1,2,3,4,5}
```

Así que para acceder a un elemento de un arreglo basta con escribir el nombre del arreglo seguido de corchetes, y dentro de ellos la posición del elemento al que quieres acceder:

```
s[1] = 2
```

El elemento devuelto por s[1] es el número 2, porque es el número que está guardado en la posición 2 del arreglo.

si quieres sumerle 1 a el elemento 1 del arreglo entonces lo que tendrías que hacer es lo siguiente:

```
int suma = 0;
int numero_a_sumar = 1;

suma = s[1] + numero_a_sumar;
cout<<"\n\tLa Suma es: "<< suma";
```

No necesitas la función test_case para realizar el código, y si la incluyes podrías ser un poco mas ordenado y específico con la operación que realizarás en la función.